# Clarification regarding a statement on exceptions

Tags: python, exception

My textbook says :

*"In Python, exceptions are errors that get triggered automatically. "*

What does it mean? I had thought about this statement for sometime but unable to understand it.

(P.S. I am a beginner in the computer field  . Please give a understandable answer for me)

Comment: it means that you don't have to add code to trigger them. they will automatically trigger when the error happens. For example, if you do `2/0` a ZeroDivisionError exception will automatically trigger, and you can capture it if you put your division in a `try except` clause

Comment: Thanks but is there anything related to error that do not trigger automatically? Why a classification? Thanks once again.

Comment: Let's say you write in a language that does not support native Exceptions for the error  `2/0` given to you by @SembeiNorimaki. In such language, an error would not be automatically reported, and if you have no visible/trivial consequence when you run your program, you may struggle to find what is the Error. It would require you spend a lot of effort trying to figure out what mistake you made.

Comment: Am I correct to conclude that exceptions are the indicators of errors that help us to identify the errors so that we can directly correct the errors and thus they prevent us from spending a lot of effort to find the error in our program?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *"In Python, exceptions are errors that get triggered automatically. "*

That's true, an even more correct definition would be the following.

> *An exception **is an event, which occurs during the execution of a program** that disrupts the normal flow of the program's instructions.*

You should imagine your interpreter (I guess you're using [`CPython`](https://python.org)) executing line after line **until an event happens**.

That event can be an **error**, that is passed to your script as an `Exception` (or sublcass) `object`.

---

> *"[...] that get triggered automatically"*

That's not completely true, you can throw (or better saying `raise`) an exception manually.

```
raise Exception("Error occurred!")
```

Comment: Thanks, is that 'trow' or 'throw' in the last paragraph?

Comment: Sorry, it was a typo. Anyway if it helped you understanding could you please accept my answer?